# Android proguard anomalies

Tags: android, proguard

After a major rewrite of an Android app, we did a round of testing with a debug build with the proguard rules enabled (a qa build, definition below).  We found and fixed a number of issues.  Everything appeared to be working as expected.   Then we did a release build and put it up on the play store as an internal test.   All kinds of things are broken.  We are uploading app bundles, not apks.  It's very helpful testing with logging enabled.

For the internal testing, I created a qa build, here's stanza for it build.gralde:

```
        qa {
        initWith debug
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
```

So what's that failing to do that the one on the play store is doing?  It's a debug build, on the play store, it's a release build, but I believe they should both have the same obfuscations rules. The qa build sure was handy, having both full logging, and the obfuscation.   Now I have bugs I need solve with very little logging (and a very slow turn around since I need to build a release, upload, and download it to a test device). Is the difference what Google is doing when it creates the apks from the bundle?  I suppose the other difference is the logging.   I suppose we might be wrapped something we shouldn't have with

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
```

The only thing I can see to do at this point is enable full logging on the release builds.

Comment: After adding logging to release, I found legit obfuscation issues.  I guess the question now is why didn't the qa build find them?  The app was exercised quite thoroughly with the qa build.